# Namespace function linker error when used in multiple classes

Tags: c++, static, namespaces

I am simply writing a function that I want to use in my code for debugging WITHOUT throwing exceptions. I want a defined variable DEBUG_MODE that when set to true causes the function to print a given message and when set to false prints nothing. I want it available to any class that imports the file without having to create a class, i.e. I include "Debug.h" and can call Debug::Log(string message).

I read about the advantages of using namespace functions so I wrote it as such but perhaps I don't understand the proper usage of namespace functions. When I include my header file with the namespace function in one class it works great, when I use it in two classes in two different files I get a linker error:

```
Error   1   error LNK2005: "void __cdecl Debug::Log(char const *)" (?Log@Debug@@YAXPBD0@Z) already defined in Foo.obj...
```

Here is the code for my namespace functions:

```
#pragma once

#include <cstdio>

// IMPORTANT: Set this to true if you want debug logging, false otherwise
#define DEBUG_MODE true

namespace Debug
{
    void Log(const char* message)
    {
        if (DEBUG_MODE)
            printf(message);
    }

    void Log(const char* messageFormat, const char* parameter)
    {
        if (DEBUG_MODE)
            printf(messageFormat, parameter);
    }
}
```

Now if I make the functions static then everything works fine, but I was under the impression that using namespace functions was the alternative to static functions in my case. I would also like to be able to define static functions in another file if possible.

What should I use? A static function? A namespace function? If the latter then how do I use namespace functions in two separate classes/files without causing the above linker error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you are missing is the `inline` keyword like so:

```
inline void Log(const char* message)
```

Without `inline`, the functions are created for each source file including your header file.

`static` would have a similar outcome, but inlining seems preferred for such a small functions.

---

Or, if you don't want to make the compiler create the code again and again in all files, you of course need to have the implementation just once in one .cpp file and leave just the declaration in the header.

In order for the DEBUG_MODE to affect it, though, you will need to do it e.g. like this:

```
#ifndef DEBUG_MODE

// Dummy implementation
inline void Log(...) {}

#else

// Implemented in Log.cpp
void Log(const char* message);
void Log(const char* messageFormat, const char* parameter);

#endif
```

Comment: I avoided inline because I will be using this function all over my code and inline essentially copies the function wherever I call it potentially making for a large executable. While it doesn't make much difference in this case it could for large functions, is there some way around that?

Comment: So perhaps I don't understand how separation of headers and implementations works (due to seldom use of C++) but how does the compiler treat the implementation differently when it is in a header vs in a cpp file? I want to understand WHY I should do what you recommend.

Comment: Compiler is invoked several times, most of the time for each .cpp file you have, and creates an object file (.o or .obj). The linker then joins all object files together to the final executable program. -- Now each of the input .cpp files can contain any number of #includes - from different parts of your code, from system, from 3rd party libraries etc. It does not make sense to compile the inner workings of all functions again and again, so you leave just the declaration in the header file and then provide its implementation in just one .cpp file. It is then compiled and in output just once.

Answer (score 1):

Try making them inline. Otherwise you could define them in a separate source file and just declare them in the header file.

If you define it in the header as a non-inline non-static function and include it in more than one source file of a program, the linker will be presented with copies of the same function in multiple object files.

There are 3 solutions:

1. Make them inline.
2. Make them static.
3. Define them in their own source file and only declare them in the
   header file.

Making them static causes the names not to be exported and they are therefore only known inside one object file. But you will still have multiple copies of the functions, but only one copy each in each object file that uses them.

Comment: Assuming I go for the latter option, why should I define such a trivial function in a separate source file?